# TFS 2015 and later - Tagging agents

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

Does anyone know if the feature to tag agents has dissapeared?
I could not find anything related to over the internet.

My idea is to have certain builds use a specific agent. On TFS 2013 I would use tagging, but i no longer see that option.
On the other hand, I see that it is possible to connect a build definition to a certain agent queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no more agent tags for TFS 2015 or later version. If you want to use a particular build definition and a specific build Agent which used to run the build.

You could add a **[user Capability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/agents/agents#capabilities)** to that specific build agent then in the build definition you put that capability as a **demand** (General tab).

Another way is directly using `Agent.Name` or `Agent.ComputerName` demands in build def or when queuing a build. Take a look at this blog: [How to send TFS build to a specific agent or server](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericparvin/2017/02/08/how-to-send-tfs-build-to-a-specific-agent-or-server/), which also support on TFS2015.

> ***Oren***: Is this feature works in TFS15 SP3?
>
> ***Reply Eric Parvin***: Yes, this should work on TFS 2015 to the newest version.

Answer (score 1):

Use [demands and capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/options#demands) for this. Add a custom capability to the build agent, and then add a matching demand to the build definition.

Answer (score 0):

Demands and capabilities would work, and you could also create a specific queue, with a single available agent in it, and set the queue to your desired build, so you would achieve the same behavior as desired one.